# Is it possible to exclude from aws S3 sync files older then x time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to use `aws s3` CLI command to sync files (then delete a local copy) from the server to S3 bucket, but can't find a way to exclude newly created files which are still in use in local machine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
find /path/to/local/SyncFolder -mtime +1 -print0 | sed -z 's/^/--include=/' | xargs -0 /usr/bin/aws s3 sync /path/to/local/SyncFolder s3://remote.sync.folder --exclude '*'
```

There's a trick here: we're not *excluding* the files we don't want, we're excluding *everything* and then *including* the files we want. Why? Because either way, we're probably going to have too many parameters to fit into the command line. We can use `xargs` to split up long lines into multiple calls, but we can't let `xargs` split up our excludes list, so we have to let it split up our includes list instead.

So, starting from the beginning, we have a `find` command. `-mtime +1` finds all the files that are older than a day, and `-print0` tells `find` to delimit each result with a null byte instead of a newline, in case some of your files have newlines in their names.

Next, `sed` adds the `--include=/` option to the start of each filename, and the `-z` option is included to let `sed` know to use null bytes instead of newlines as delimiters.

Finally, `xargs` will feed all those `include` options to the end of our `aws` command, calling `aws` multiple times if need be. The `-0` option is just like `sed`'s `-z` option, telling it to use null bytes instead of newlines.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can only Include/ Exclude based on Filename. So the only way I see is a realy dirty hack.
You could run a bash script to rename all files below your treshhold and prefix/ postfix them like TOO_NEW_%Filename% and run cli like:

```
--exclude 'TOO_NEW_*'
```

But no don't do that.

Comment: I guess i'm not gonna do that but this solution definitely inspired me to this solution. 1. cronjob with s3 sync without deleting local copy 2. cronjob with bash script to delete old files. what do you think?

Comment: Mhhh, on first sight that sounds feasible. But what happens when for whatever reason (net problems, downtime?) your first job won't work? Then you would delete your files without ever send them to s3, right?

Comment: Ohh.. you right. what about this: bash script to copy files older then x hours and only if the copy was succeeded delete the file?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely ignoring the newer files is the default behavior. We can read in `aws s3 sync help`:

> The default behavior is to ignore same-sized items unless the local version is newer than the S3 version.

If you'd like to change the default behaviour, you've the following parameters to us:

> - `--size-only` (boolean) Makes the size of each key the only criteria used to decide whether to sync from source to destination.
> - `--exact-timestamps` (boolean) When syncing from S3 to local,  same-sized
>     items  will  be  ignored  only  when  the timestamps match exactly. The
>     default behavior is to ignore same-sized items unless the local version
>     is newer than the S3 version.

To see what files are going to be updated, run the `sync` with `--dryrun`.

Alternatively use `find` to list all the files which needs to be excluded, and pass it into `--exclude` parameter.